# How to perform a function in python/streamlit by clicking on a point in a graph

Tags: python, vega-lite, streamlit

I want to perform a function when I click on a point in the graph.

Currently I am using Python, Streamlit and Vega-Lite for the graph. I want to create something that gives me more information about a clicked point by executing a python function.

So I want to perform the `search()` function but instead of giving arguments myself I want to give the a, b and c values of the clicked point.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(200, 3),columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

df = df.append({'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1}, ignore_index=True)

st.vega_lite_chart(df, {
 'mark': {'type': 'circle', 'tooltip': True},
 'encoding': {
     'x': {'field': 'a', 'type': 'quantitative'},
     'y': {'field': 'b', 'type': 'quantitative'},
     'size': {'field': 'c', 'type': 'quantitative'},
     'color': {'field': 'c', 'type': 'quantitative'},
 },
})

def search(arg1, arg2, arg3):
   return df.loc[(df['a']==1) & (df['b']==1) & (df['c']==1)]

searched = search(1,1,1)
searched
```

[image: image graph in Streamlit]

I know it's possible to click on a graph with vega-lite like the following example https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/point_href.html. But instead of going to Google I want to preform a python function.

Is there some type of graph that can be used for this type of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interactions with graphs are not supported yet.

For further details see this [link](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/plotly-click-events-in-streamlit/1419).